# 404 Error when migrating live Wordpress site to local server XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I am trying to migrate a live Wordpress site to the local server using XAMPP. I followed the [tutorial](https://webnus.net/live-wordpress-site-to-localhost/) to import database and put project file in htdocs folder, updating urls to localhost urls, but I can only access home page, other pages are 404 not found.

What I did:

- Export database file
- git clone the project into xampp/htdocs
- Create and Import database file
- Update oldsite url with localhost/myproject in these tables:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_links SET link_url = replace(link_url, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_links SET link_image = replace(link_image, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com', 'newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

- Update the wp-config file with the new database name, user and password

Then I can successfully load the home page, but other pages are still not available, 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

Normally that means that your sites .htaccess file is not working correctly so the best thing to do is Empty the contents of the .htaccess file and go into your admin area and reset your permalinks. This will force a correct rewrite on your .htacces file and should fix your problem.